# Client/Server sending large files

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcplistener, httplistener

I'm about to write a server application, which should be able to receive large files from multiple sources (quiet like all other FTP client/server apps).

But I'm not sure what would be the best approach, and need some advice.

The client would sent XML data to the server, which would look something like:

```
<Data xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataFiles" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Category>General</Category>
    <Files>
        <DataFile>
            <Extension>.txt</Extension>
            <Filename>test4</Filename>
            <Bytes>"Some binary data"</Bytes>
        </DataFile>
    </Files>
</Data>
```

I started out creating a **HTTPListener** as my server, but it seems to struggle a lot on large files on the server end (basicly since the context is received as one packet not fragmented, and when the server does deserialize the XML data received, it load it into memory, which would be a no-go for large files.

I then moved on to a **TcpListener** to go a layer lower, which seems to work fine on large files, since they are sent fragmented, but leave me to do a lot of work to append the package on the server-side when request are received.

I also moved shortly over **WCF** as a possibility, but my lack of experience with this technology, made me leave that approach again.

**What would you do?** Which .NET tool of the great .NET toolbox would you use to create a FTP server/client?

There is a lot of threads about TcpListeners etc., thats not what I seek here. I need advices on which approach I should go with, and best practices.

*EDIT:*
Forgot to mention that the idea behind it is more like a FTP proxy (client send file to server > Server store file locally > Server sends it to a 3rd part location > Server clear the locally stored file when seding file to 3rd part location is succefully done).

EDIT 17-11-15:

Here is an example code of how I do my HTTP Server:

```
public class HttpServer
{
    protected readonly HttpListener HttpListener = new HttpListener();

    protected HttpServer(IEnumerable<string> prefixes)
    {
        HttpListener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        while (HttpListener.IsListening && Running)
        {
            var result = HttpListener.BeginGetContext(ContextReceived, HttpListener);
            if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] {result.AsyncWaitHandle, _shutdown}) == 0)
                return;
        }
    }

    protected object ReadRequest(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        using (var input = request.InputStream)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(input, request.ContentEncoding))
        {
            var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return data;
        }
    }

    protected void ContextReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpListenerContext context = null;
        HttpListenerResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            var listener = ar.AsyncState as HttpListener;
            if (listener == null) throw new InvalidCastException("ar");
            context = listener.EndGetContext(ar);
            response = context.Response;
            switch (context.Request.HttpMethod)
            {
                case WebRequestMethods.Http.Post:
                    // Parsing XML data with file at LARGE byte[] as one of the parameter, seems to struggle here...
                    break;
                default:
                    //Send MethodNotAllowed response..
                    break;
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Do some properly exception handling!!
        }
        finally
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                context.Response.Close();
            }
            if (response != null)
                response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client is using:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    GetExtensionHeaders(client.Headers);
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    client.UploadFileAsync(host, fileDialog.FileName ?? "Test");
    client.UploadFileCompleted += ClientOnUploadFileCompleted;
    client.UploadProgressChanged += ClientOnUploadProgressChanged;
}
```

Please note, that the client is supposed to sent data (as XML) to the server, which will deserialize the data received (using a filestream server-side), as written previously.

Here is my TcpServer example:

```
public class TcpServer
{
    protected TcpListener Listener;
    private bool _running;

    public TcpServer(int port)
    {
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        Console.WriteLine("Listener started @ {0}:{1}", ((IPEndPoint)Listener.LocalEndpoint).Address, ((IPEndPoint)Listener.LocalEndpoint).Port);
        _running = true;
    }

    protected readonly ManualResetEvent TcpClientConnected = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public void Start()
    {
        while (_running)
        {
            TcpClientConnected.Reset();
            Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTcpClientCallback, Listener);
            TcpClientConnected.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
    }

    protected void AcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            var listener = ar.AsyncState as TcpListener;
            if (listener == null) return;

            using (var client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar))
            {
                using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    //Append or create to file stream
                }
            }

            //Parse XML data received?
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            TcpClientConnected.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm calling you out on the following "since the context is received as one packet not fragmented". Can you explain exactly what this means?

Comment: Well, what I noticed is, that when the client is sending a file to the server (using TcpClient as client), a lot of tcp packages are sent to the host/server according to wireshark trace. But the context doesn't exist the waithandle until the complete HTTP/XML package is sent.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've read very large HTTP streams from the client using HttpListener without having to wait for the entire payload to reach the server. Let's see some code. I think you're doing it wrong.

Comment: It is very possible that I'm doing something wrong. I'll post some of my code when I'm back on a wire connection again (This afternoon).

Comment: Http uses TCP as the  transport layer.  So you won't see the http on wireshark until the tcp is fully transported.  There really isn't any http sent it is tcp.   Wiresharp doesn't decode the http until it gets all the tcp.  Also FTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  FTP is just an application that runs on tcp.  A tcp packet is maximum ~1500 bytes and large message are sent using multiple tcp.  I would probably use TCP for large files which uses the least amount of overhead.

Comment: @jdweng The advantage of using the HTTP Listener above TCP Listener, is that package received is easy to parse, since the internal protocol will use XML serialization/deserialization in both ends (client and server), which means the data sent will be xml data. I'm not sure how this will be supported if I use TcpListener raw? Since the packets received in server end will be fragmented into packets of a 1500bytes size, that need to be deserialized. But since the packet is chunked into pieces, I guess this would be better to handle big files sent as byte[] in the XML body?

Comment: What.  With TCP there is no parsing because the first character is the start of the xml identifier.  With TCP and HTTP all the fragmentation is handled by the low level Ethernet driver in the PC and the application doesn't see any of the fragmentation.  When using Sync Read all the character will come in one lump.  when using Async Read data will come in blocks of various different sizes depending how the Ethernet drive reconstructs the fragments.

Comment: @jdweng So if I create a TcpListener server-side, and use the NetworkStream of the TcpClient.GetStream(), it should be possible to append the stream into a file, within the same tcp session, and when the data stream is done, read and deserialize the xml file written, without carring about how fragmentation is handled?

Comment: Yes.  Fragments will be in order and just need to be appended together.  It is not necessary to create a file.  The xml can be parsed from a string.

Comment: @jdweng The reason why I would save it in a file, is that the XML will contain the file as byte[] element, which would create a very large string it not loaded into a file, and if the file is huge, this will soak the memory on my server which could be an issue. And since the file part should be sent to another srv, the temporary file would fit fine.

Comment: @spender uploaded some code examples.

Comment: The method you use is really up to you. HTTP can be displayed on a webpage and can be made easier than TCP.  Besides that there isn't much of an advantage either way except there HTTP messages will be a little larger due to the http headers.  Do you know why the http method struggles on large files?  Have you used a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to determine what is causing the struggles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new empty MVC application

[image]

Next add a new controller to the `Controllers` folder,

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace UploadExample.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult File(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            file.SaveAs(@"c:\FilePath\" + file.FileName);
        }

    }
}
```

Now all you have to do to upload a document is post it to your site as multipart form data...

```
void Main()
{   
    string fileName = @"C:\Test\image.jpg";
    string uri = @"http://localhost/Upload/File";
    string contentType = "image/jpeg";

    Http.Upload(uri, fileName, contentType);
}

public static class Http
{
    public static void Upload(string uri, string filePath, string contentType)
    {
        string boundary         = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundaryBytes    = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=\"{0}\";\r\nContent-Type: {1}\r\n\r\n";
        string formitem         = string.Format(formdataTemplate, Path.GetFileName(filePath), contentType);
        byte[] formBytes        = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);

        HttpWebRequest request  = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.KeepAlive       = true;
        request.Method          = "POST";
        request.ContentType     = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.SendChunked     = true;

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Write(formBytes, 0, formBytes.Length);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*4];
            int bytesLeft;

            while ((bytesLeft = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesLeft);

            requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
        }

        Console.WriteLine ("Success");    
    }
}
```

## EDIT

If you run into issues, edit your Web.Config file, it's likely that you're hitting request length limits...

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
</system.web>
```

Another thing I missed out (but now edited) was the send chunked property on the webrequest its self.

```
request.SendChunked = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your well detailed example. I might have missed it, but the server side should be running as a self-hosted windows service, and not depending on a IIS service to run. Would your example be able to run without a IIS service (sorry for my lack of asp.net experience)